# Doubling dimension vs other metric dimensions

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, dimension-theory

For separable metric spaces, three fundamental notions of [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension)
 are equivalent:
$$ \text{dim }X = \text{Ind }X = \text{ind }X ,$$

Where does the [doubling dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space)
 fit into the picture?

Comment: First the first fact is topological (rather to state in term of metrizable spaces). Doubling dimension is a metric property (bilipschitz invariant, not topological). Now the question is certainly too broad: every possible rant about doubling dimension seems to answer the question.

Comment: So there is no relation between the doubling dimension ddim(X) and the toplogical dimension dim(X)? One can be finite and the other infinite?

Comment: It sounds obvious to construct metric spaces with finite (covering/inductive) dimension and infinite doubling dimension. In the other direction, finite doubling dimension implies finite dimension if I'm correct (e.g., by Assouad's embedding), but I don't know about explicit bounds.

Comment: I'll be happy to accept the obvious answer -- for both directions.

Comment: It may happen that the topological dimension is equal to the infimum of the doubling dimensions over all metrics generating the topology of the space.

Comment: Thanks @taras   Do you have a reference?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich No I do not. I know only that the topological dimension equals the infimum of packing dimensions over all admissible metrics and this is a theorem of Pontryagin-Snnirelmann (if I remember well) from 1930-ies.  Anyway, such problems reduce to constructing good metrics on the Menger cubes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one direction, a rapidly branching tree will have very high doubling dimension, while having topological dimension $0$ (or $1$, if you include the edges). In another direction there is a bound, and this is discussed in the nice paper below (on the first page):

*Le Donne, Enrico; Rajala, Tapio*, [**Assouad dimension, Nagata dimension, and uniformly close metric tangents**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1512/iumj.2015.64.5469), Indiana Univ. Math. J. 64, No. 1, 21-54 (2015). [ZBL1321.54059](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1321.54059).

Answer (score 2):

Let ${\rm dim}_H X$ and ${\rm dim}_d X$ denote the Hausdorff and the doubling dimension respectively. It is easy so see that ${\rm dim}_H X\leq  {\rm dim}_d  X$. Indeed, if ${\rm dim}_d X=s$, then we can cover a ball of radius $r$ by at most $2^{s}$ balls of radius $r/2.$ Therefore we can cover a ball of radius $1$ by $2^{ks}$ balls of radius $2^{-k}$ so we can estimate the Hausdorff measure $H^s(B(x,1))\leq C 2^{ks}2^{-ks}= C<\infty$ and hence  ${\rm dim}_H X\leq s={\rm dim}_d X$. On the other hand by Theorem 8.14 in [[1](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387951041)] (the proof is very short) we have that the Hausdorff dimension is greater than equal to the topological dimension so finally we get 
$$ 
\text{dim }X = \text{Ind }X = \text{ind }X\leq \text{dim}_H X\leq \text{dim}_d X. 
$$
As pointed by Igor Rivin the Hausdorff dimension of a rapidly branching tree can be arbitrarily large.

[[1](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387951041)]  J. Heinonen, [*Lectures on analysis on metric spaces*](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387951041). Universitext. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2001.
[MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=CC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=heinonen&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=Books&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=5&mx-pid=1800917).